# Number of zeros of $f(z)=z^5+iz^3-4z+i$ in $1<|z|<2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> *Given $f(z)=z^5+iz^3-4z+i$ in $\{1<|z|<2\}$ determine the number of zeros.*

I wanted to use Rouché, not sure how to choose the functions:

I chose $g(z)=z^5+iz^3$, so $2<|g(z)|<40$, but

$\begin{align}|f(z)-g(z)|=|z^5+iz^3-4z+i-(z^5+iz^3)|=|-4z+i|\le |i|+4|z|<9\end{align}$

Even $g(z)=z^5-4z$ didn't work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $|z|=1$ check the modulus of the terms. $|z^5|=1$, $|iz^3|=1$, $|-4z|=4$ and $|i|=1$. So $-4z$ is dominant. Note that $|z^5+iz^3+i|\le |z^5|+|iz^3|+|i|=3\lt 4=|-4z|$ so by Rouche we have that $z^5+iz^3-4z+i$ has one zero inside $|z|=1$.

Also note that $|iz^3-4z+i| \le |iz^3|+|-4z|+|i|=8+8+1=17\lt 32=|z^5|$ so there are $5$ zeros inside $|z|=2$.

So there are $5-1=4$ zeros in the annulus.

Comment: One must always note that there are no zeros on $|z|=1$.

Comment: @Pedro of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Rouche twice, once on the circle $|z|=1$ and once on the
circle $|z|=2$. In each case try first taking $g(z)$ to be the "dominant
term" in the polynomial $f(z)$. You expect the dominant term to be different in each case.

Comment: thank you for your answer